# Blender black areas after baking

Tags: texturing, texture-baking, baking, units

[image: image after baking]

After the baking process is completed, black areas appear. When I searched on youtube, I saw that I needed to set the metallic value to zero, but the metallic value is already zero and the problem persists. How can I properly bake?

[image: original object]

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your object? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @moonboots I have attached the blend file

Comment: So what object are you trying to bake on what other object?

Comment: @moonboots I connected the problematic images(with black areas) I obtained after baking to the first object so that you can see the problem better. The other is the original object I put into the baking process. it's like before and after

Comment: The unwrap is incorrect, some UVs must overlap, unwrap again, with the Smart UV Project option for example, and bake, and it works

Comment: @moonboots Problem solved. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unwrap is incorrect, some UVs are overlapping, unwrap again, with the *Smart UV Project* option for example, bake, and it will work.